# Trigger touch event onclick

Tags: javascript

I have an element which works only ontouch(start), and I want to make that onclick will trigger ontouch (for non-touchable devices, such as my pc). like:

```
element.onclick = element.touchStart();
```

or:

```
element.onclick = element.touch();
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new touch event using `new Event`, and dispatch it to the element, using `dispatchEvent`  method of `event.target`.

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div");

div.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  var event = new Event('touch');
  e.target.dispatchEvent(event)
});

div.addEventListener("touch", (e)=>{
  console.log("touched");
});
```

```css
#test{
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><div>
```